# How to calculate individual chance over a total 10% of 60 iterations?

Tags: statistics, percentages

I'm developing a game that needs to calculate a 10% chance over a second of shooting against the player. The problem is, this calc is run every frame at a 60 frame rate.

So I need the individual percentage of each frame, that could reach the 10% after 60 frames.

I tried => 1/10/60 = 0.166% on each frame, but this doesn't work well.

How to do it?

Comment: Your interpretation of the problem suggests that the probability of the player to get shot after $10$ seconds is $100$%. Now, I'm pretty sure that's not what you meant to happen. If you want the probability of a player getting shot to be $10$%, then the same probability should be applied for $1$ second, $10$ seconds and $\frac{1}{60}$ second. In other words, if the probability at every frame is $10$%, then the probability at every $60$ frames will also be $10$%.

Comment: Got your idea, but in pratical didn't worked. Every frame it tries to shoot the player, so 10% on every frame and after 60 frames (equal 1 second), the chance would be 600%, so it WILL shoot every second. I want 10% of chance to shoot on every second, BUT the algoritm runs every frame (60 frames per second). Got it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want it on average to shoot every sixth frame, so that's a $1/6$th probability per frame ($16.6\%$), not $0.166\%$.

Comment: If 16,6% would be once every 60 frames, once every 600 frames would be 1,66%, right? This makes sense! Thanks